# Razer Orochi и Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: hp

Здравствуйте. У меня есть мышь Razer Orochi. Хочу поставить Ubuntu на ноутбук HP Pavilion dv6-3124er. Есть ли полноценные драйвера на данную мышь и будет ли работать "TurboBoost" на Intel i7?

---

Hello I have mouse Razer Orochi. I want to put Ubuntu on a laptop HP Pavilion dv6-3124er. Is there a full-fledged driver on this mouse and would work "TurboBoost" on the Intel i7?

Answer (score 0):

привет!

Loads of mouses and other input devices work out-of-box. So just go on and try it out. I cannot see why it shouldn't work right away.

Obviously "TurboBoost" works under Ubuntu. There is no way, though, to verify this. At least, I do not know of any.

Успехов!

Comment: I assume by full fledged he meant a driver that supports all buttons and functions of that mouse, which is mostly not the case, but you can map buttons in org configuration if needed.

Comment: а драйвер для настройки самой мыши (настройка макросов, подсветки) есть? Так то я понимаю, что работать она будет. (Английский - плохо)

_________________________

Driver and software for the mouse settings (setting the macro, lights) is? So I understand that it will work. (my English is bad)